# I want to put a column between columns using mdb query in C#

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I want to put a column between columns using mdb query in C#.

Queries like Ara do not work.

First, adding the column was successful.

I want to add a column called Denominator after the Numerator.

"ALTER TABLE CleanerMotorNEW CHANGE COLUMN Denominator Denominator NUMBER 0 AFTER Numerator"

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to do something like this:

```
"ALTER TABLE CleanerMotor ADD COLUMN Denominator INTEGER AFTER Numerator"
```

Comment: I tried But it doesn't work.

I already have data in the table, because of that

Or is there a version problem?

Comment: Syntax error.
i try this
ALTER TABLE CleanerDIO ADD column DIOMechanicalID TEXT(100) AFTER DIOType

Comment: I mean can you post the exact text of the complete error?